# XML is not producing in a right way

Tags: xslt

I am working on this snippets, but, i am getting the expected output.

Here is my input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GovTalkMessage xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader">
  <EnvelopeVersion>1.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <GovTalkDetails>
    <Keys/>
  </GovTalkDetails>
  <Body>
    <NameSearch>
      <ContinuationKey>fcb844eELdiGt/AO3sMH2IGP8Amoxy+wewviAdon</ContinuationKey>
      <RegressionKey>fcb844eJyt0ttO20moxy+wewviAdon</RegressionKey>
      <SearchRows>100</SearchRows>
      <CoSearchItem>
        <CompanyName>WILLIAM ROSE LTD</CompanyName>
        <CompanyNumber>07905646</CompanyNumber>
        <DataSet>LIVE</DataSet>
        <CompanyIndexStatus>DISSOLVED</CompanyIndexStatus>
        <CompanyDate></CompanyDate>
      </CoSearchItem>
    </NameSearch>
  </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

And, here is my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="GovTalkMessage/Body/NameSearch/CoSearchItem">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output is

```
<CoSearchItem>
  <CompanyName>WILLIAM ROSE LTD</CompanyName>
  <CompanyNumber>07905646</CompanyNumber>
  <DataSet>LIVE</DataSet>
  <CompanyIndexStatus>DISSOLVED</CompanyIndexStatus>
  <CompanyDate></CompanyDate>
</CoSearchItem>
```

Please someone help where is the problem.

Comment: And your *actual* output is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following to achieve my desired output

```
<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='GovTalkMessage']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='NameSearch']/*[local-name()='CoSearchItem']">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

and, it works. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

The first template that is applied is for the root node, and you need to specify namespaces if they are used at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:g="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/g:GovTalkMessage/g:Body/g:NameSearch/g:CoSearchItem"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<xsl:output/>` and `<xsl:strip-space/>` are just to fix the indentation.

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CoSearchItem xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader">
   <CompanyName>WILLIAM ROSE LTD</CompanyName>
   <CompanyNumber>07905646</CompanyNumber>
   <DataSet>LIVE</DataSet>
   <CompanyIndexStatus>DISSOLVED</CompanyIndexStatus>
   <CompanyDate/>
</CoSearchItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you can also use the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute. That way you don't have to use a prefix in your xpaths.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader" 
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/govtalkheader" 
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="GovTalkMessage/Body/NameSearch/CoSearchItem"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And to make explicit what Daniel Haley has trusted you to understand:  your problem is that you didn't use namespace prefixes in your XPath expressions, though your elements are all in a namespace.